# How to choose an appropriate method to fit this data?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, dataset, supervised-learning

I want to fit a model curve to the plot below. Each fine curve corresponds to a vehicle driving a certain distance and measureing some quantities of interest in certain timesteps (discrete measurements combined to curves). In the plot you see several fine curves over each other, discovering a certain pathern I want to capture. Furthermore, the drives happen not always on the same daytime (have daytime variable at hand).

[image: DATA]

More drives added:

[image: MORE DATA]

1. Aim: Estimate the curvy nature of the y-values dependent on the x-axis (distance) only and add a confidence intervall around the estimated curve.

or

2. Aim: Estimate the curvy nature of the y-values dependent on the x-axis (distance) and account for the variability of the y-values at a certain distance point by considering another independent variable daytime.

Since my data is of quantitative nature and by starring at the plot I would most certainly use either GAM (with s, lo or poly) or KNN and than maybe with cross-validation check which one gives the best testMSE. But yet this are a lot of options.

**Does someone has some recommandations which models I should consider to programm for the given data?**

If you use google search you often end up in some tables which lead you in a certain direction (e.g. https://help.xlstat.com/s/article/which-statistical-model-should-you-choose?language=en_US), but in the end there are often still several options among I have to choose.

Do not hesitate to ask for more information if needed!

(Data preparations in MATLAB, Statistical analysis in R, have tons of data)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. In it's current form your question is too broad in my opinon - the question of "what model to choose" is a matter for entire books. For the problem you described however this can probably be answered.

Comment: Thank you, I adjust the question to focus more on the given data problem.

Comment: By eye, it looks like you could do pretty well for aim 1 by just taking the mean of the curves at each x value. Use bootstrapping to get a confidence/prediction band (resample entire curves, not individual timepoints). I don't see much need here for a fancier method.

Comment: Thank you @user20160
Insight: The different drives (curves) do not always take measurements at the same distance but rather do measure independent from each other. To follow your recommandation either we interpolate and choose means at uniform distances for all curves or do something like KNN.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you don't know (in general) unless you try :)

Say you want to choose between SVM, a Random Forest and KNN.
You evaluate their performances on a test set, ending up with three scores (one per model). How to tell which model is better than the other? You use statistics.

Most of the things you want to know on this subject are here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.12808.pdf.

(On a separate note, I think in your specific case you need a model that can handle time-series, as it appears that your data is dependent on time.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So its pretty normal to have tons of coding work until you have just choosed your model. For me its seemed like doing to much extra work if I try a lot of models and compare them.

About TS:
I first thought too it would be nice data for TS. But, since one vehicle-drive is not made always on the same daytime, but just on the same route, it seems to me that TS is not possible to use? Or can you link a TS approach that could be used in that case?

Do you have other recommandations for models to use for the given data?

Comment: yeah, you have to code a bit. Essentially, there isn't one definite model for a given task (see the "no free lunch theorem", so you have to choose it every time the task changes. As regards TS data, your data is perfectly okay. The dependency you have is not on time as in "time of the day" (although it could have some influence), but it means that if you fix the route and you have information of where you are at time t, you can predict where you will be at time t+1. Hope it is clear. Any approach for handling sequential data should be fine for your use case.

Comment: Probably in your case I would use an ARIMA model, you can google for it, there's plenty of resources.

Comment: I see your point now, thank you!

Actually, I already red myself into timeseries before my question-post, but where I also struggled was that for example in https://rpubs.com/riazakhan94/arima_with_example they take like one data curve for an interval of time, whereas I have several curves for the interval [0,2500].

I do not really know how to treat this data with TS. Do I have to take just one of the drives? Or somehow combine them together to get one long curve?

Comment: My idea once was that I first combine the drives together to one estimated line (hence my posted question) and maybe afterwords use TS on the estimated line to get an overall TS dependency..

Comment: You can do as you say, but I'm not sure it will work, as you have a feature (time of day) which varies for each TS. Perhaps Recurrent Neural Networks or Hidden Markov Models are better suited in your case.